# Display coupon description and id on thankyou.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

Basicly, I would like to display the coupon used on Woocommerce thankyou.php. Here is the code I have added

```
$coupons = $order->get_items( 'coupon' );
foreach ( $coupons as $item_id => $item ) {
echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$item['name']."</b></span>";
$post = get_post( $item_id );
echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
 }
```

However, only the coupon code is shown while the description does not.

Here is where I placed my code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}


if ( $order ) : ?>



<?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My Account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php 
        $coupons = $order->get_items( 'coupon' );
        foreach ( $coupons as $item_id => $item ) {
            echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$item['name']."</b></span>";
            $post = get_post( $item_id );
            echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
         }
    ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

    <ul class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">
        <li class="order">
            <?php _e( 'Order Number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="date">
            <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="total">
            <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <?php if ( $order->payment_method_title ) : ?>
        <li class="method">
            <?php _e( 'Payment Method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?></strong>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id ); ?>
```

```
<p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: can you explain what type of description it is ?

Comment: It is the coupon's description.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals','change_discount',10,3);
function change_discount($total_rows, $order, $tax_display){ 
    if (  $order->get_total_discount() > 0 ) { 
        $coupons = $order->get_used_coupons(); 
        $total_rows['discount'] = array( 'label' => __( 'Coupon code: '.implode(",",$coupons), 'woocommerce' ), 'value' => '-' . $order->get_discount_to_display( $tax_display ), ); 
    } 
return $total_rows; 
}
```

Comment: This is working code from some other developer. please modify according to your needs  function.php (active theme)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, I hope it will work for you:

```
<?php
 add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
 function apply_product_on_coupon() {
        global $woocommerce;

        if ( ! empty( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
             $my_coupon = $woocommerce->cart->get_coupons() ;
             foreach($my_coupon as $coupon){

                if ( $post = get_post( $coupon->id ) ) {
                        if ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) {
                            echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$coupon->code."</b></span>";
                            echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

If this will not work then use coupon shortcode plugin and call shortcode on  the thankyou page
      https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-coupon-shortcodes/

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[coupon_shortcode]'); ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry Raj Kumar Bhardwaj, your code only works when the coupon is applied to the cart. When you have proceed to checkout,it doesn't show anything. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Yes, but it does not show anything. I need to show the coupon used on the order page too. ( My-account / order ). Can you please help me? My code shows the coupon name only, but it does not show the description. However,your code works on cart page(before checkout)

Comment: would you like to show something this : http://awesomescreenshot.com/00f60dctc1 please check the screenshot                                                                                                         http://awesomescreenshot.com/09760dd2d4

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this

```
    if( $order->get_used_coupons() ) {

        $coupons_count = count( $order->get_used_coupons() );

        echo '<h4>' . __('Coupons used') . ' (' . $coupons_count . ')</h4>';

        echo '<p><strong>' . __('Coupons used') . ':</strong> ';

        $i = 1;
        $coupons_list = '';

        foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon) {
            $coupons_list .=  $coupon;
            if( $i < $coupons_count )
                $coupons_list .= ', ';
            $i++;
        }

        echo '<p><strong>Coupons used (' . $coupons_count . ') :</strong> ' . $coupons_list . '</p>';   }
```